# Is Joerg Schilling’s “sdd” a full replacement for “dd”?

Tags: linux, debian, administration, disk-utility

I'm trying to use `sdd` on my Debian system, and can't get one set of options to work. They do work in `dd` so I am wondering if I am specifying them incorrectly, or if `sdd` didn't implement them, or something else.

What I want to do is

```
sdd if=/dev/hdh1 of=/bay5/imagebay1 bs=4096 conv=sync,noerror
```

If I leave out the `conv=...` option, it works. Or at least starts copying data.

```
sdd if=/dev/hdh1 of=/bay5/imagebay1 bs=4096
```

Can you shed a bit of light?

Comment: you can associate your Super User account with your Stack Overflow account and take ownership of your original question by clicking on your name at the top of the page and using the *Accounts* tab.

Comment: please don't double-post.  i'm not sure why the migrated version of this question hasn't already been associated with your account; it should've been.  i'm filing a bug on that.

Comment: filed a [bug report on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49629/user-account-association-failed-to-fix-lost-ownership-on-migrated-question) -- this should get the ownership issue fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [manpage](http://cdrecord.berlios.de/private/man/sdd.html) you will see sdd does not support a 'conv' option.